# best way to write builder and how to use nonlocal : python

Tags: python, python-3.x, builder

when I need create some complex object I prefer write builder for it.
so far that was:

```
class Builder(object):
   def before(self):
      do..
   def build(self):
      do stuff
   def after(self):
      do..
```

it's singleton so I must keep in mind do not use self for building parameters (important for threads), so I need pass many parameters among builder's methods, or pass they as unfinished(half-built) object. or create builder-object each time when I want create new building object, which is not not good aproach.

however when I start using python 3, I prefer builder as function:

```
def builder():
    param1 = None
    param2 = None
    def before(self):
        do..
    def build():
        nonlocal param1
        build object ...
    def after(self):
        do..
    def ...(self):
        do..
```

it's seems to be lighter and thread safe, isn't it? any risk here?
where/how else can I aplplied nonlocal?

I am right now rething pythonic aproach to builder pattern I what I found is:

```
class Builder:
   def build(self):
       param = None
       def _build_step1():
```

which give me parametrization of builder class and easy way to use building object inside build method and nested methods.

Comment: So why is it a singleton?

Comment: well, just to avoid create many builder objects (it's heavy, so I prefer methods), I write sth where performance really count, but do not have time to test and timeit all this stuff.

Comment: I am willing to bet that your performance concerns are completely misguided. If the builder object itself is small, it's much cheaper to just allocate and de-allocate them repeatedly than jumping through hoops necessary to reduce the downsides of the singleton. If there's some huge read-only data structure the builder needs, you can share *that* among builders rather than sharing one builder between multiple clients. One can cache or recycle objects just fine without introducing singletons. You're misusing that design pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You should be just using keyword arguments instead of Java patterns in Python—in other words, I fail to see why you would be using the builder pattern in Python if there are other, perfectly usable and better ways of composing objects.

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age=UNKNOWN, gender=MALE):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.gender = gender

people.append(Person("Erik"))
people.append(Person("John", age=27))
people.append(Person("Pamela", gender=FEMALE))
people.append(Person("OldDude", gender=MALE, age=99))
```

Comment: but I am about case when composing object requires parsing or sth else to do - many stuff to just find parameters for object constructor
so I really want separate builder to keep building logic.
Is a pattern a language specific?

Comment: Yes, "pattern" is typically a nice way of saying "workaround for a language limitation"—most Java/C#/C++ patterns stem from limitations of expression in those languages. But maybe your object construction is really **so** complicated that it warrants a dedicated builder mechanism... although I suspect optional arguments + some internal helper/parser methods should still do it while keeping the interface "plain" Python.

Comment: Actually I'd be curious to see what is it exactly that you think necessitates the use of the builder pattern.